# Showing $[a, \infty) = \bigcap (a - \frac{1}{n}, \infty) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to show: $[a, \infty) = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a - \frac{1}{n}, \infty) $

If we take $x \in [a, \infty)$, then $x > a > a - \frac{1}{n} $ for all $n$. Hence, $x$ is in the intersection.

Similarly, if $x$ is in the intersection, then $x > a - \frac{1}{n} \implies x = a \implies x \geq a \implies x \in [a , \infty )$

Is this a valid solution? Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: $x \geqslant a > a-\frac1n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first half of your argument, showing that $[a,\infty)\subseteq\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\left(a-\frac1n,\infty\right)$, is correct, but the second half is not. It is certainly not true that $x>a-\frac1n$ implies that $x=a$, which is what you’ve written, though probably not what you meant. What is true is that if $x>a-\frac1n$ for **all** $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, then $x\ge a$; this is what you need, but it’s easier to prove it indirectly.

It’s probably easiest to show that $\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\left(a-\frac1n,\infty\right)\subseteq[a,\infty)$ by showing that if $x\notin[a,\infty),$, then $x\notin\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\left(a-\frac1n,\infty\right)$, so suppose that $x\notin[a,\infty)$; then $x<a$, so $a-x>0$. By the Archimedean property there in an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\frac1n<a-x$, and hence $x<a-\frac1n$, and I expect that you can easily finish it from here.

Comment: does it not follow that if $a - b < \frac{1}{n} $ for all $n$, then $a = b $ ?

Comment: @Emprendedor: No, it follows that $a\le b$.

Comment: So To finish the proof: $x < a - 1/n$ implies $x < a$ which implies $x \in (- \infty , a) $ which implies $x$ cannot be in the intersection. Is this correct?

Comment: @Emprendedor: No, this is circular. What is true is that $x<a-\frac1n$ implies that $x\notin\left(a-\frac1n,\infty\right)$, which in turn implies that $x$ is not in the intersection. If you already knew that $x\in(-\infty,a)$ implied that $x$ is not in the intersection, you’d already know the result.

Comment: thanks you for your help Brian. One last question: Can we also show by same method above that $ ( - \infty , a] = \bigcap (- \infty, a + \frac{1}{n}) $ ?

Comment: @Emprendedor: You’re very welcome. Yes, that argument will be the mirror image, so to speak, of this one.